# Java bytecode - one label for each statement

Tags: java, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

The `javac` compiler adds a line number label to each instruction that corresponds with a new line in the source code. As a consequence, when multiple statements are listed on one line, they all fall under the same line label (`L1` in the case shown below, with two print statements on the same line).

Is it possible to have the compiler output one label per statement? I'd like to group instructions by statements (instead of by line), for a bytecode analysis task.

#### Source code

```
package com.example;

public class Foo {
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("test");
        System.out.println("test"); System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

#### Bytecode

*(Compiled with Oracle JDK 8, debugging output enabled)*

```
// class version 52.0 (52)
// access flags 0x21
public class com/example/Foo {

  // compiled from: Foo.java

  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 3 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Object.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/example/Foo; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x1
  public bar()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 5 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "test"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 6 L1
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "test"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "test"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L2
    LINENUMBER 7 L2
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/example/Foo; L0 L3 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to format the code beforehand?

Comment: I think your best bet is to format the code as Yassin suggested. Otherwise, it's a matter of modifying Javac, which is much more involved.

Comment: Not ideal, but indeed probably my best option. @YassinHajaj feel free to formulate as an answer to the question, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @gandreadis Alright I'll provide an answer with IntelliJ for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way for me would be to open the project with a code editor and to format the whole project before compiling it. This would ensure that all statements are on their own line (as common code style mandates one statement per line).

I'll give you the way to go using IntelliJ IDEA (of which the community edition is free)

1. Open the project with IntelliJ
2. Right click on the root folder of the project in the left "Project" pane.
3. Click on "Reformat Code" then OK

[image: Reformat Code]